# Grouping one QRadioButton into several QButtonGroups

Tags: c++, qt

I have, for example, four `QRadioButton`s `rb1`, `rb2`, `rb3`, `rb4`. I set `rb1` and `rb3` checked:

```
rb1->setChecked(true);
rb3->setChecked(true);
```

Also, I have four `QButtonGroup`s : `bg12`, `bg34`, `bg13` and `bg24`, and make first two non-exclusive(they are by default):

```
bg13->setExclusive(false);
bg24->setExclusive(false);
```

The first case: I add `rb1` and `rb2` to the `bg12`, and `rb3` and `rb4` to the `bg34`. Then I add all the buttons to the grid layout, show the widget, and all that stuff, everything works as expected(two buttons are active, and button in one row excludes the other in its row).

The second case: I add `rb1` and `rb2` to the `bg12`, and `rb3` and `rb4` to the `bg34`. Then I add `rb1` and `rb3` to the `bg13`, and `rb2` and `rb4` to the `bg24`. Now it does not work as I expected, they all behave like «free» buttons, and I can check/uncheck any of them. So, what am I doing wrong?

**Upd:** I've also tried it with `QPushButton`s(so, no exclusivity and such stuff), and it just looks like if button is already in a `QButtonGroup`, and I add it do another one, it doesn't belong to the first anymore :(

I guess, you might wonder why would I do this wierd stuff - I'll explain. I want to keep a vector of pairs of `QRadioButton`s, and a button in each pair must exclude the another in its pair(they represent two exclusive states), so I want to group buttons in each pair in an exclusive `QButtonGroup`(like `bg12`and `bg34` in the example) and also add, for example, all the first buttons of each pair to another `QButtonGroup`(non-exclusive, like `bg13` from the example) and give it an id. So, I would be able to handle state changes with one of the signals `QButtonGroup` class provides us and the id. Maybe there's a simplier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QAbstractButton` holds one `QButtonGroup` as member, so a button can only belong to one group.

But for the non-exclusive group, you can use `QSignalMapper`s instead.

Comment: Wow, QSignalMapper is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!